# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a simple SQL Query that is getting fired in DB which is in Server Side while executing query sometimes it shows an error message :

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

My query is :

```
If sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlconn.Open()
Txn = sqlconn.BeginTransaction

cmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand
cmd.Transaction = Txn
    strSql = "insert into " & tableName _
    & " (RepSerNo,ProductType,ProductID,ProductName,Qty,GrpQty,IDSNo,CubicalNo,BatchNo,BalanceId," _
    & "VernierID,UserID,UserName,PrDate,PrTime,Side,Unit,DecimalPoint," _
    & "WgmtModeNo,InstruID,Nom,PosTol,NegTol,NomEmpty,PosTolEmpty,NegTolEmpty," _
    & "NomNet,PosTolNet,NegTolNet,RepoLabel1,RepoLabel2,RepoLabel3,RepoLabel4,RepoLabel5," _
    & "RepoLabel6,RepoLabel7,RepoLabel8,RepoLabel9,RepoLabel10,RepoLabel11, " _
    & "RepoLabel12,RepoLabel13,RepoLabel14,RepoLabel15,RepoLabel16,RepoLabel17," _
    & "RepoLabel18,RepoLabel19,RepoLabel20)" _
    & " values(" _
    & RepBatchSrNo & "," & ProductType(cno) & "," & Chr(39) & ProductId(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Product_Name(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Qty(cno) & "," & GrpQty(cno) & "," & IDSNo(cno) & "," & CubicNo(cno) & "," & Chr(39) & BatchNo(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & balanceIdforTabCap(cno) & Chr(39) & "," _
    & Chr(39) & VernierId(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & UserId(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & UserName(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & DT & "," & Chr(39) & TM & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & SIDE(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & unit(cno) & Chr(39) & "," & DecimalPoint(cno) & "," _
    & wgmtmodeNo & "," & instruID(cno) & "," & NomValLmt(cno, 2) & "," & UppValPer(cno, 2) & "," & LwrValPer(cno, 2) & "," & NomValLmt(cno, 3) & "," & UppValPer(cno, 3) & "," & LwrValPer(cno, 3) & "," _
    & NomValLmt(cno, 0) & "," & UppValPer(cno, 0) & "," & LwrValPer(cno, 0) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 1)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 2)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 3)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 4)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 5)) & Chr(39) & "," _
    & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 6)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 7)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 8)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 9)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 10)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 11)) & Chr(39) & "," _
    & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 12)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 13)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 14)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 15)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 16)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 17)) & Chr(39) & "," _
    & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 18)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 19)) & Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39) & Trim$(ReportLabels(cno, 20)) & Chr(39) & ")"

    addToLogAudit("from savedata_new() for master:" & strSql)

    cmd.CommandText = strSql
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0 'already included command timeout to 0 still its not working
    res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have already Included Cmd.Commandtimout=0 still I'm Getting same error message
Your help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to create queries because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, as well as SQL syntax errors. Use SqlParameters. [How can I avoid SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200256/how-can-i-avoid-sql-injection-attacks)

Comment: `cmd` is a type which is IDisposable, so should be in a `Using` block. The way you are doing `sqlconn` implies that you are trying to keep it alive, which is a bad idea, connection pooling means it works very efficiently to open a new connection for each thing that you're doing - and the SqlConnection type is also IDisposable, so should also be in a `Using` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout you are getting is on the connection, not on your query.

Comment: Are you sure? The stack trace says it's coming from `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`...

Comment: @Richardissimo `at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError`

Comment: @Richardissimo Plus there is absolutely nothing in the query (horrible coding style notwithstanding) that would cause the SQL server to timeout.

Comment: Fair enough. I would have expected an error to occur when they opened the connection if there was something wrong there; but the code doesn't even show whether the Command is in a `using` block, let alone the connection (which should be as well), so we don't have much to go on. I think you've probably nailed it.

Comment: @Richardissimo Right, it's hard to reconstruct all the missing code.

Comment: So guys  what should i do now or you need some more info about it.

Comment: @vivekpadelkar Show how you are creating SqlConnection object and connecting to the database. Show how you are constructing the SqlCommand object.

Comment: @AngryHacker I have edited the question please check whether you can get any hint from it. thanks

Comment: @vivekpadelkar So 2 things.  After the 1st line (e.g. sqlconn.Open()), examine the .State property.  Then, at the end, copy the contents of `strSql` to the clipboard.  Open Sql Server Management Studio and run this command manually.  See what you get.

Comment: @AngryHacker i have run this command in my laptop this command run successfully but in the client site im getting this error so i took client DB to test and this working fine too. i dont know why this not working in client site.

Comment: So you are saying "it works on your machine"?  Put a lot of debugging statements then take it to the client site again.  My guess the connection string is incorrect at the client site.